# is it possible to send the host name on a $resource request?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, angularjs-1.5

I am using AngularJS 1.5 and ngResource.
I have an array of objects, each object containing an IP address that I would like to send HTTP GET requests to in iteration. For example:

```
var arr = [{ip: '127.0.0.1', name: 'myHost'},{ip: '1.2.3.4', name: 'differentHost'}]
arr.forEach(function (obj) { // Send requests to obj.ip });
```

If i use $http service and just concatenate the IP address, it works fine.
However, I want to use $resource service because I have a set of actions, but when i use the $resource to do so, it doesn't consider my host name/IP address as parameter.

```
    var Host = $resource('http://:ip:49221/:action', { ip: '@ip' }, {
       status: {method: 'GET', params: {action: 'currentStatus'} }
    });
    Host.status({ip: '1.2.3.4'}).$promise.then(function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

I get: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://:ip:49221/currentStatus

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/d9roMDWEbPpyG5upKSrv?p=preview

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On XMLHttpRequest by definition you cannot do cross domain request but there is some lead you can explore.

[How to configure Angular $resource (ngResource) to pull data from another domain using CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554270/how-to-configure-angular-resource-ngresource-to-pull-data-from-another-domain)

[Is it Angular $http.defaults.useXDomain really neccessary in CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147196/is-it-angular-http-defaults-usexdomain-really-neccessary-in-cors)

And be careful there are some issues on ie8/9 :
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2956